# Restricting access to Wordpress admin by IP address

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

When restricting access to the Wordpress admin via IP, is it necessary to to include `/wp-login.php` and `/wp-admin`?

Answer (score 1):

yes, then only people from that IP will be able to access either of them. Please note restrictions on wp-admin will create havoc with any calls to admin-ajax.php. This can be resolved by whitelisting 127.0.0.1

Comment: Great, thanks for your reply. Why do we need to add `wp-admin`? Won't all admin traffic pass through `wp-login.php`?

Comment: I agree it would make it harder to gain access, but someone who wanted to could. It would be like locking the gate to a castle which has no walls.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as correct if I have answered your question.